# Snakemake shadow rule when program writes to /tmp

Tags: relative-path, snakemake, absolute-path

I am using Snakemake to run the [defense-finder](https://github.com/mdmparis/defense-finder) program. This program creates and overwites generic temporary files in `/tmp/defense-finder`, i.e. the file names do not contain unique identifiers. When running my rule across separate cores on different input files, Snakemake crashes due to clashes in `/tmp/defense-finder`.

It appears that [Shadow rules](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#shadow-rules) can help when different jobs write to the same files within the working directory. Is there a way to use Shadow rules when a program writes to the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: I don't think shadow rules will help with that. Sometimes you can hack a solution using the `TMPDIR` environment variable, but it looks like defense-finder hardcodes the path. You would have to alter the source code.  (It looks like someone, possibly you, has already filed a bug report on its github page.)

Comment: Thanks @Marmaduke, I appreciate you looking into this. It's a shame that editing the source code seems to be the only solution. It was indeed me that filed the bug report!

Comment: @Marmaduke perhaps you should turn your comment into an answer. Effectively the answer is that paths are hardcoded in defense-finder and there is not much snakemake or another workflow manager can do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @Marmaduke's comment that file paths are hard-coded, a temporary workaround is to force snakemake to run the defense-finder jobs one at a time while allowing other jobs to run in parallel. You can do this with the [resources](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#resources) directive:

```
rule defense_finder:
    resources:
        n_defense= 1,
    input: ...
    output: ...
    shell: ...
```

then run with:

```
snakemake --resources n_defense=1 -j 10 ...
```

Comment: Thank you @dariober, this is a great workaround